# Odd values when enumerating a list

Tags: haskell

As part of a larger function definition, I needed to allow the domain (i, n) of a function to increment from i to n at varying rates. So I wrote:

```
f (i, n) k = [i, (i+k)..n]
```

into GHC. This returned odd results:

```
*Main> f (0.0, 1.0) 0.1
[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.30000000000000004,0.4000000000000001,0.5000000000000001,0.6000000000000001,0.7000000000000001,0.8,0.9,1.0]
```

Why does GHC return, e.g., 0.30000000000000004 instead of 0.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *i*, *n*, and *k* are rational, you could go the infinite-precision route:

```
f :: (Rational, Rational) -> Rational -> [Rational]
f (i, n) k = [i, (i+k) .. n]
```

The notation may require a bit of getting used to:

```
ghci> f (0%1, 1%1) (1%10)
[0 % 1,1 % 10,1 % 5,3 % 10,2 % 5,1 % 2,3 % 5,7 % 10,4 % 5,9 % 10,1 % 1]
```

Think of the `%` as a funny looking fraction bar.

You could view approximations with

```
import Control.Monad (mapM_)
import Data.Ratio (Rational, (%), denominator, numerator)
import Text.Printf (printf)

printApprox :: [Rational] -> IO ()
printApprox rs = do
  mapM_ putRationalToOnePlaceLn rs
  where putRationalToOnePlaceLn :: Rational -> IO ()
        putRationalToOnePlaceLn r = do
          let toOnePlace :: String
              toOnePlace = printf "%.1f" (numFrac / denomFrac)
              numFrac, denomFrac :: Double
              numFrac    = fromIntegral $ numerator   r
              denomFrac  = fromIntegral $ denominator r
          putStrLn toOnePlace
```

The code above is written in an imperative style with full type annotations. Read its type as transforming a list of rational numbers into some I/O action. The [`mapM_`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v%3AmapM_) combinator from `Control.Monad` evaluates an action (`putRationalToOnePlaceLn` in this case) for each value in a list (the rationals we want to approximate). You can think of it as sort of a `for` loop, and there is even a [`forM_`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v%3AforM_) combinator that's identical to `mapM_` except the order of the arguments is reversed. The underscore at the end is a Haskell convention showing that it discards the results of running the actions, and note that there are `mapM` and `forM` that do collect those results.

To arrange for the output of the approximations via [`putStrLn`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Prelude.html#v%3AputStrLn), we have to generate a string. If you were writing this in C, you'd have code along the lines of

```
int numerator = 1, denominator = 10;
printf("%.1f\n", (double) numerator / (double) denominator);
```

The Haskell code above is similar in structure. The type of Haskell's `/` operator is

```
(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
```

This says for some instance `a` of the typeclass `Fractional`, when given two values of the same type `a`, you'll get back another value of that type.

We can ask `ghci` to tell us about `Fractional`:

```
ghci> :info Fractional
class (Num a) => Fractional a where
  (/) :: a -> a -> a
  recip :: a -> a
  fromRational :: Rational -> a
    -- Defined in GHC.Real
instance Fractional Float -- Defined in GHC.Float
instance Fractional Double -- Defined in GHC.Float
```

Notice the `instance` lines at the bottom. This means we can

```
ghci> (22::Float) / (7::Float)
3.142857
```

or

```
ghci> (22::Double) / (7::Double)
3.142857142857143
```

but not

```
ghci> (22::Double) / (7::Float)

<interactive>:1:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' against inferred type `Float'
    In the second argument of `(/)', namely `(7 :: Float)'
    In the expression: (22 :: Double) / (7 :: Float)
    In the definition of `it': it = (22 :: Double) / (7 :: Float)
```

and certainly not

```
ghci> (22::Integer) / (7::Integer)

<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer)
      arising from a use of `/' at :1:0-27
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the expression: (22 :: Integer) / (7 :: Integer)
    In the definition of `it': it = (22 :: Integer) / (7 :: Integer)
```

Remember that Haskell's `Rational` type is defined as a ratio of `Integers`, so you can think of [`fromIntegral`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Prelude.html#v%3AfromIntegral) as sort of like a typecast in C.

Even after reading [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell: Numbers](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html), you'll still likely find Haskell to be frustratingly picky about mixing numeric types. It's too easy for us, who perform infinite-precision arithmetic in our heads or on paper, to forget that computers have only finite precision and must deal in approximations. Type safety is a helpful reality check.

Sample output:

```
*Main> printApprox $ f (0%1, 1%1) (1%10)
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

The definition of `printApprox` probably seemed comforting with all the helpful signposts such as names of functions and parameters or type annotations. As you grow more experienced and comfortable with Haskell, such imperative-looking definitions will begin to look cluttered and messy.

Haskell is a *functional* language: its strength is specifying the what, not the how, by assembling simple functions into more complex ones. Someone once suggested that Haskell manipulates functions as powerfully as Perl manipulates strings.

In [point-free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree), the arguments disappear leaving the *structure* of the computation. Learning to read and this style does take practice, but you'll find that it helps write cleaner code.

With tweaks to the imports, we can define a point-free equivalent such as

```
import Control.Arrow ((***), (&&&))
import Control.Monad (join, mapM_)
import Data.Ratio (Rational, (%), denominator, numerator)
import Text.Printf (printf)

printApproxPointFree :: [Rational] -> IO ()
printApproxPointFree =
  mapM_       $
  putStrLn    .
  toOnePlace  .
  uncurry (/) .
  join (***) fromIntegral .
  (numerator &&& denominator)
  where toOnePlace = printf "%.1f" :: Double -> String
```

We see a few familiar bits: our new friend `mapM_`, `putStrLn`, `printf`, `numerator`, and `denominator`.

There's also some weird stuff. Haskell's `$` operator is another way to write function application. Its definition is

```
f $ x = f x
```

It may not seem terribly useful until you try

```
Prelude> show 1.0 / 2.0

<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Fractional String)
      arising from a use of `/' at :1:0-13
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional String)
    In the expression: show 1.0 / 2.0
    In the definition of `it': it = show 1.0 / 2.0
```

You could write that line as

```
show (1.0 / 2.0)
```

or

```
show $ 1.0 / 2.0
```

So you can think of `$` as another way to write parentheses.

Then there's `.` that means function composition. Its definition is

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

which we could also write as

```
(f . g) x = f $ g x
```

As you can see, we apply the right-hand function and then feed the result to the left-hand function. You may remember definitions from mathematics textbooks such as

[image: rendered composition example]

The name `.` was chosen for its similarity in appearance to the raised dot.

So with a chain of function compositions, it's often easiest to understand it by reading back-to-front.

The `(numerator &&& denominator)` bit uses a [fan-out combinator](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Arrow.html#v%3A%26%26%26) from `Control.Arrow`. For example:

```
ghci> (numerator &&& denominator) $ 1%3
(1,3)
```

So it applies two functions to the same value and gives you back a tuple with the results. Remember we need to apply `fromIntegral` to both the numerator and denominator, and that's what `join (***) fromIntegral` does. Note that `***` also comes from the `Control.Arrow` module.

Finally, the `/` operator takes separate arguments, not a tuple. Thinking imperatively, you might want to write something like

```
(fst tuple) / (snd tuple)
```

where

```
fst (a,_) = a
snd (_,b) = b
```

but think functionally! What if we could somehow transform `/` into a function that takes a tuple and uses its components as arguments for the division? That's exactly what [`uncurry (/)`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Auncurry) does!

You've taken a great first step with Haskell. Enjoy the journey!

Comment: This answer is excellent. The above solution works better than expected (it solved some false Bool values from being reported in a few 'brute force this calc. problem' functions. The definition of 'printApprox' is over my head, but I don't mind reading Rationals (and, of course, the goal is that it /won't/ be over my head in a while).

Answer (score 9):

Because IEEE floating point arithmetic can't express decimal numbers precisely, in general. There is always a rounding error in the binary representation, which sometimes seeps to the surface when displaying the number.

Depending on how GHC converts floating-point numbers to a decimal representation, you might find that on Windows it displays the result as the expected `0.3`. This is because Microsoft's runtime libraries are smarter than Linux and Mac about how they present floats.

EDIT: This may not be the case. The number `0.3` will encode as the integer `3fd3333333333333` when using IEEE floats, whereas `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` will produce a number that encodes as `3fd3333333333334`, and I don't know whether Microsoft's runtime libraries are tolerant enough to round back to `0.3` when displaying this.

In any event, a good example of the different handling is to type `0.3` into a Python interactive shell. If it's Python 2.6, you'll get back `0.29999999999999999`, and if it's 2.7, it will display `0.3`.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently I have a lot of wikipedia to read! Thanks.

Comment: @danportin See also "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" at http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Greg: A decade later, I've found your comment the most valuable.

Comment: @danportin You're welcome! I'm glad the information was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A better way of doing this is more along the lines of

```
map (/10) [0 .. 10]
```

This takes whole numbers, thereby avoiding the float problem, and divides each one by 10.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Just because you aren't putting a decimal in the number doesn't mean it isn't one. So while the numbers may be "whole", you aren't avoiding the float problem. In fact, because of the way you've written it, you risk making the problem worse (because you're trying to convince yourself that the numbers aren't using floating-point).

A better way of doing this would be to use `Rational`s (or some sort of `Ratio`-using type.

Comment: The basic problem stems from the floating binary representation.  0.1 decimal is a recurring binary fraction, so you get rounding errors.  However all integers up some very large value have precise representations as floats, so you are guaranteed not to get rounding errors as long as you stick to them.  You can always specify IEE-488 arithmetic in the documentation if it makes you feel more comfortable.